# Why does my UITableView not load cell contents completely?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Seems that my table loads partially, with the rest loading after I've scrolled up and down a few times. Undoubtedly, this has to do with my `[[self myTableView] reloadData];` and my placement between `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated,-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated,-(void)viewDidLoad` although I can't put my finger on it. There is no request for data being made in this case; I am only trying to have all the specified data load at once when the app starts up.

```
#import "PreViewController.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "FlipsideViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
#import "Reachability.h"

@interface PreViewController ()

{
    NSMutableArray *arrayNo;
}

@end

@implementation PreViewController

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkForReachability) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    [reachability startNotifier];

    NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    if(remoteHostStatus == NotReachable)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle: @"Please check your network connection and try again."
                          message: @""
                          delegate: nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
 }

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{    

   NSString *arts = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Arts and Museums"];
   NSString *coffee = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Coffee and Bakeries"];
   NSString *tours = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tours and Festivals"];
   NSString *hotels = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hotels and Inns"];
   NSString *leisure = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Leisure and Recreation"];
   NSString *music = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Live Music"];
   NSString *bars = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Night Clubs and Bars"];
   NSString *food = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Restaurants"];
   NSString *shopping = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Shopping"];
   NSString *transportation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Transportation"];

   [arrayNo addObject:arts];
   [arrayNo addObject:coffee];
   [arrayNo addObject:tours];
   [arrayNo addObject:hotels];
   [arrayNo addObject:leisure];
   [arrayNo addObject:music];
   [arrayNo addObject:bars];
   [arrayNo addObject:food];
   [arrayNo addObject:shopping];
   [arrayNo addObject:transportation];

   [[self myTableView] reloadData];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   arrayNo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   [[self myTableView] setDelegate:self];
   [[self myTableView] setDataSource:self];
}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return 1;

}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arrayNo count];
}

- (UIFont *)fontForCell
{
   return [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  if (!cell)
  {
      NSLog(@"CREATING NEW CELL");
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  }
  else
  {
      cell.textLabel.text = [arrayNo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
      cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
      cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(100/255.0) green:(130/255.0) blue:(255/255.0) alpha:1.0];
  }
  return cell;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Comment: Temporary disable all the code in your viewWillAppear method, see if the issue goes away.

Comment: I copied everything except the viewWillAppear method, and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Why are you waiting until `viewDidAppear:` to load your array? Side note - please get rid of all of the calls to `stringWithFormat:`. Only use `stringWithFormat:` when you actually have a string you need to format. Example: `NSString arts = @"Arts and Museums";`.

Comment: I guess I don't understand how taking `viewWillAppear` would have affected it? Maybe I need to update to the latest version of XCode...

Comment: I don't either. I'm not sure what in the answer you accepted helped either. There's nothing wrong with the "else" part. Do you get blue text when you do it the way Thilina suggested?

Comment: @rdelmar The answer makes perfect sense. As originally written, the `cellForRow...` method only populated the cell's textLabel if it was a reused cell. The label needs to be set every time, not just during reuse. The other `textLabel` settings only need to be made when the cell is created, not when it is reused.

Comment: @rmaddy, not under the conditions that I ran -- if I use a table view controller created in IB, then dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: always (in my experience) returns a cell, even though that's not what Apple's docs say. I don't know if this changed in iOS 6, but I've seen no difference between using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: and dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath. I ran the OP's code as written, and it worked fine.

Comment: @rdelmar We don't know if IB is involved here. It's certainly not needed for this code. I never use IB so the call to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` returns `nil` lots of times. Regardless, code should be written properly. If there is a check for `nil`, the `if` and `else` parts should be written to handle both possible results regardless of whether IB is used or not. The accepted answer is written correctly and will handle all possible cases.

Comment: @rmaddy, yes, I agree, that code should be written correctly, and that if you're checking for nil, you need to handle both cases. But, if you are using a storyboard and iOS 6, that code in the if clause will never run and people need to be aware of that. Lots of people do use IB, and there seems to be undocumented behavior, that dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: seems to always return a cell (from a storyboard created cell).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, change the code like this, (your else part is incorrect)

```
    if (!cell)
      {
         NSLog(@"CREATING NEW CELL");
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
         cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
         cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
         cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(100/255.0) green:(130/255.0) blue:(255/255.0) alpha:1.0];
      }

  cell.textLabel.text = [arrayNo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Thanks Thilina! As far as I can tell, removing the `else` worked for me.

Comment: What's incorrect about the else part? That code in the if part won't even run if he did the table view controller in a storyboard.

Comment: @rdelmar, if (!cell) then else part does not run, that means when you create a new cell you don't set the cell.textLabel.text (cell.textLabel.text = [arrayNo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];) thats the problem, removing else solves that problem. Go through the question, I can't see the word "storyboard" in this :)

Comment: Well, there must be something different in his setup if that actually fixed the problem. I copied his code and it worked fine. In fact the if part of the statement doesn't run, and the else part does. If you add a table view in IB, no matter whether you use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: or dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:, you get a cell all the time. It's never nil, which is why (for me at least) the else part of the statement ran.

Comment: @rdelmar, The UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; does not guarantee you get a cell object always, that's why we normally check if(!cell) then create a new one inside if statement. I can't believe that you don't know this

Comment: Yes I'm quite aware of that -- I've made dozens of projects with table views. It's true that it doesn't guarantee it (but it seems to work anyway), which is why you should use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: which does guarantee it.

Comment: @rdelmar Don't forget that the use of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` requires the use of `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:`. And these are all iOS 6.0 or later. Those of us supporting iOS 5 can't use these.

Comment: @rdelmar, iOS develpment is not always "storyboards". and in this question I don't see the word "storyboard" and I don't want to argue with you anymore, also I'm not going to comment to this again. to dequeue with particular cell identifier, you should (enqueue) create a cell with that particular cell identifier. unless your are not getting a cell in return when you call dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier. these are basics. if you have problems with it, go google it "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier"